# Single instance check using mutex

Tags: .net, vb.net, mutex

I'm trying to implement single instance application using mutex.
the application can run only one instance from a given directory.
i tried to implement it in Applicationsevents class but it's not working.

I replicated it with a test harness with a single form.
my ApplicationEvents.vb code:

```
   Private Sub SingleInstanceCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup

        Dim strLoc As String = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
        Dim fileInfo As IO.FileSystemInfo = New IO.FileInfo(strLoc)
        Dim sExeName As String = fileInfo.Name

        strLoc = strLoc.Replace("\", "//")

        Using mutex As New Threading.Mutex(False, "Global\" + strLoc)
            If Not mutex.WaitOne(0, False) Then
                File.WriteAllText("c:\log.txt", "instance already running")
                Environment.Exit(1)
            End If

            GC.Collect()


        End Using

    End Sub
```

it runs multiple instances.

Things I am not able change: 
1.project setting has "Enable Application framework" ticked
2. ApplicationEvents.vb handles UnhandleException which means i cant have a module as startup.

please helpppp!!!

Comment: While not directly related to your problem, you should be extremely wary of calling GC.Collect manually, it will almost always cause the garbagecollector to perform worse than it otherwise would have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwe34f1k.aspx#Y0):

```
Dim newInstance as boolean
myMutex = New Threading.Mutex(True, "Global\" + strLoc, newInstance)
```

You can check the 'newInstance' value, if it created a new one, then there was no previous instance, otherwise if it didn't create a new one then another instance of your app did, so you can exit...

Also you need to keep the mutex around for the life of your application: your mutex will only stay around for the scope of your using statement, then it is released. You have to store it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I tried suggested in my test application which has just a form, and it worked. but if i do the same in my real world windows app it does not work. which confuses me even more there has to be some setting particular to solution or projects I think.

Comment: It shouldn't be anything related to solution or project settings, the important thing is to keep the mutex around, make it a member variable, and don't wrap it in 'Using'

Comment: In that case something else must be killing the mutex. according msdn "The application raises the Startup event before the main application runs.". I don't have anything in that sub except the code to check mutex. and it works fine on test form. my application uses wcf,threading , timers etc.. so some part of the code is disposing mutex

Comment: If you have the 'Using' statement in your sub, it will dispose of the mutex when it gets to the 'End Using'... Can you post more of your code?

Comment: Finally got it working, i tried your suggestion and made the mutex a member variable:  
`Private mutex As Mutex`. but it doesnt explain why it works on a test app with a local variable.  Thanks for your help